# Retrieve radio input value in a CDHtmlDialog based application

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I'm working on a MFC application based on html dialogs.

I've encountered lot of struggle for exchanging datas between the html and the c++ code, but I finally managed to make it working.
I'm retrieving without any problems values from text inputs (`DDX_DHtml_ElementText()`), selects (`DDX_DHtml_SelectValue()`), checkboxes (`DDX_DHtml_CheckBox()`) but I can't find out how to get the value from a radio input ...

I don't understand how to use the `DDX_DHtml_Radio()` method.

```
void DDX_DHtml_Radio( 
   CDataExchange* pDX, 
   LPCTSTR szId, 
   long& value  
);
```

I guess `value` will store 0, 1, 2 etc. according to the checked radio input,
but what do I have to store in the `szId` ? I imagine it needs the id of the html element that group all the radio buttons, but there is zero documentation or zero example about it ... I've tried with the input id but value is still null.

in html I just have :

```
<input id="radio-https" type="radio" name="http-switch" value="https"/>
<input id="radio-http" type="radio" name="http-switch" value="http" checked="checked"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh ... I tried with radio's name and it worked :

```
DDX_DHtml_Radio(pDX, _T("http-switch"), httpSwitchValue);
```

the only microsoft documentation is unclear ...

> szId
>
> The value that you specified for the HTML control's ID parameter.

I'd mark this as an answer as I saw many posts on the internet about it without any answer